# How to remove a field in a users id in active directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, userid

What I am trying to do is that there are a lot of user id's in our Windows Active Directory that when you go to the properties of the id's, in the "Office" field, it says (for this example) "test this".  I was wondering if there is a way to write in PowerShell to find all the users in Active Directory with "test this" written in the "office" field, and then to remove the words "test this" from the Office field.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the -LDAPFilter param for `Get-AdUser`, like so:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter “(office='test this')”
```

Should give you a listing of all the users with 'Test this' in their office property.  Run that first and confirm it gives you the list you'd like.

Next, to mass change the value:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter “(office='test this')” | Set-AdUser -Clear office -whatif
```

Run that once in `WhatIf` mode to see what would happen, and if you're happy with it, then remove `-Whatif` to run it in production.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I got it by doing this:

Comment: Get-ADUser -filter {(Office -eq "test this")} -SearchBase "OU=People,OU=Inactive,DC=domain,DC=com" | Set-AdUser -Office $null